# Alternatives way to convert mobi file to txt

Tags: kindle, conversion, mobi

I've been trying for a long time to convert a .mobi file to .txt, but it always gives an error. I've tried dozens of apps (online and offline), but it always gives an error. Could anyone help me?

It is a dictionary, available on this website:
http://eb.lv/downloads/wn3infpt.mobi

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with the text once you get it, but it is possible the conversion routines are expecting a standard book and not really handling a dictionary. You might have better luck if you downloaded calibre (https://calibre-ebook.com) and use the KindleUnPack plugin to simply extract the html files from the mobi file and then use some other tool to remove the html tags from that.

Comment: Hello Eliezer, welcome to the Ebooks.SE! Will you please describe the error(s) you get, so we can concentrate on them, for finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install (or use a portable version) of a .mobi reader application such as [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/), or [Document Viewer](https://www.androidsis.com/en/apps-to-view-and-edit-android-documents/).
2. Select all text (<kbd>Clr</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in *Okular*) in the viewer.
3. Copy it (<kbd>Clr</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in *Okular*).
4. Paste from clipboard into a text editor, such as [Notepad++ for Windows](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) or [Kate for Linux](https://kate-editor.org/) or Monospace for Android.

*Voilà, c'est fini.*

Of course, this only applies to *unprotected* .mobi files, i.e., without DRM.